# EF Core one-to-many without Foreign Key (FK)

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-core, one-to-many

Are there ways to make one-to-many (abstract) relation without using SQL foreign keys?

I know it could be made by joining 2 non-related tables. But is it possible to use EF Core default navigation tools?

Comment: Shortly - no. Currently EF Core (similar to EF6) supports only FK relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want that because you can't add a foreign-key to your entity

So, you can solve that so:

You have a entity

```
Group
```

and you want a

```
List<User>
```

but your User can't be assigned to one group.
So you create a

```
GroupUser
```

entity which has a foreign key for the

```
List<GroupUser>
```

and a navigation property to the User

This is called a many-to-many relationship

Comment: I want to avoid to use FK for some important reasons. I think joining tables is the most efficient way in this case. But if you want to save entity with many nested levels it's easier to do with EF.